# Amount bug when giving items

Tags: lua, fivem

I need your help for a minute.

We have the problem that players can assign more things in the inventory than normally possible (example: I don't have "25" sandwiches but if I enter "025" as value I can give 25 to another player).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Code-snippet is here:

(server-side):

```
RegisterNetEvent('grv_inventory:giveItem')
AddEventHandler('grv_inventory:giveItem', function(name, count, target)
    local _source = source
    local xPlayer = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(_source)
    local xTarget = ESX.GetPlayerFromId(target)

    if item == 'bandage' or 'bread' or 'bulletproof' or 'clip' or 'contract' or 'cuffs' or 'cuff_keys' or 'drill' or 'fixkit' or 'jewels' or 'medikit' or 'meth' or 'phone' or 'water' or 'kroeten' or 'kroeten_pooch' or 'ephi' or 'aramidfasern' or 'aramid' or 'kevlar' or 'holz' or 'schraube' or 'huelse' or 'radio' or 'bauxit' or 'aluminiumoxid' or 'aluminium' or 'eisenerz' or 'magazin' or 'trauben' or 'traubenverarbeitet' or 'lspdstandard' or 'orangen' or 'orangenverarbeitet' or 'lsfstandard' or 'weedsamen' or 'weed' or 'joint' or 'kocher' or 'tfcoupon' or 'ffcoupon' or 'teddy' or 'rose' or 'srose' or 'kaffee' or 'cola' or 'steine' or 'fib1' or 'fib2' or 'fib3' or 'lspdweste1' or 'lspdweste2' or 'lspdweste3' then
    xPlayer.removeInventoryItem(name, count)
    xTarget.addInventoryItem(name, count)
    TriggerClientEvent('esx:showNotification', target, "Du hast " ..count.. "x " ..name.. "  bekommen ")

    TriggerClientEvent('grv_inventory:setMax', source, count)
    end
end)
```

(client-side):

```
RegisterNUICallback('give', function(data, cb)
    toggleField(false)
    SetNuiFocus(false, false)
    local playerPed = GetPlayerPed(-1)
    loadAnimDict('anim@mp_snowball')
    local player, dist = ESX.Game.GetClosestPlayer()

    if player == -1 or dist > 3.0 then
        ESX.ShowNotification('Es ist keine Person in der Nähe')
    else
        TaskPlayAnim(PlayerPedId(), 'anim@mp_snowball', 'pickup_snowball', 8.0, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
        Citizen.Wait(1300)
        ClearPedTasksImmediately(playerPed)
        TriggerServerEvent('grv_inventory:giveItem', data.item, data.amount, GetPlayerServerId(player))
        ESX.ShowNotification(("Du hast jemanden %sx %s zugesteckt"):format(data.amount, data.label))
    end
    
    cb('ok')
end)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues:

1. The comparison `if item == 'bandage' or 'bread' ... then` is not going to do what you expect it to do, as `bread` will be evaluated as `true` (as it's not compared with `item` value), so the entire expression will be evaluated as `true` regardless of what the actual value or `item` is. You need to rewrite it as `it item == 'bandage' or item = 'bread' ... and so on`
2. I don't see any comparison with available items, so either it's happening somewhere else (and is not applied because of the first issue) or is not done.